# Python SQLite how do you do partial searches using '?' placeholders?

Tags: python, sqlite

Say that my query looks like this:

```
q = SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE ?
cursor.execute(q, some_query_value)
```

This doesn't seem to be doing a "contains" search, so instead I tried doing this

```
q = SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE %?%
cursor.execute(q, some_query_value)
```

But python didn't seem to like this. What's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try putting quotes around your query string and putting a wildcard in your query value:

```
q = '''SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE ?'''
some_query_value = '%test%'
cursor.execute(q, [some_query_value])
```

Comment: @Rob now that you mention it.... I think mysql wants a tuple there.  I'll believe you that sqlite wants a list and make that change.

Answer (score 8):

The `%` wildcards are part of the value to interpolate; use string concatenation or formatting to add this into the value to search for, not in the query:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE ?"
cursor.execute(q, ('%' + some_query_value + '%',))
```

or

```
q = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE ?"
cursor.execute(q, ('%{}%'.format(some_query_value),))
```

Now `sqlite3` can properly quote the value-with-wildcards for interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a self-contained example demonstrating how to query using wildcards.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('create table methodists (name text)')

c.executemany("insert into methodists VALUES (?)",
              [['George Lucas'], ['George W. Bush'], ['W. C. Handy']])

c.execute('select name from  methodists where name like ?', ['George%'])
print ', '.join(name for name, in c.fetchall())

c.execute('select name from methodists where name like ?', ['%W.%'])
print ', '.join(name for name, in c.fetchall())
```

Result:

```
George Lucas, George W. Bush
George W. Bush, W. C. Handy
```

Comment: Hmm, our of curiosity, what's the commit for? I haven't been using that in my code and haven't encountered any issues so far, but I may have simply not found the bugs yet.

Comment: [Cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). I found it in the example I started with and didn't bother to analyze whether it was needed.  It isn't needed, so I've deleted that line in a recent edit.

Comment: My guess it would be needed for updating existing entries, but I could be wrong.